# $\Omega_{L/k}=L\otimes_K\Omega_{K/k}$ when $L/K$ finite separable

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm trying to prove that when $L/K$ finite separable one has $\Omega_{L/k}=L\otimes_K \Omega_{K/k}$. The standard proof for that says that $L=K[X]/(f)=K[\alpha]$ (with $f(X)=\sum_i a_iX^i$) and uses the conormal exact sequence
$$ (f)/(f^2)\to L\otimes_{K[X]}\Omega_{K[X]/k} \to \Omega_{L/k}\to 0$$
Then we rewrite
\begin{align*}
 L\otimes_{K[X]}\Omega_{K[X]/k}&=L\otimes_{K[X]}\Omega_{K\otimes_k k[X]/k}\\
&=L\otimes_{K[X]}\left( K[X]\otimes_K\Omega_{K/k} \oplus K[X]\otimes_{k[X]}\Omega_{k[X]/k} \right)\\
&= L\otimes_K\Omega_{K/k}\oplus L\otimes_{k[X]}k[X]dX\\
&= L\otimes_K\Omega_{K/k}\oplus LdX
\end{align*}
and we see (no?) that under these isomorphisms 
$$ f\mapsto \sum_i \alpha^i\otimes da_i+f'(\alpha)dX$$
As $L/K$ is separable $f'(\alpha)\neq0$ and here comes my problem: all the author conclude that the term $LdX$ is then cancelled in the coker of $(f)/(f^2)$ and only stays $L\otimes_K\Omega_{K/k}=\Omega_{L/k}$.

But there is also the term $\sum_i \alpha^i\otimes da_i$ and one should get something like
$$ L\otimes_K(\Omega_{K/k}/\oplus_i Kda_i)=\Omega_{L/k}$$

Where is my stupid mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the annulation of $f$ means is that in $\Omega_{L/k}$, $d\alpha$ is in the $L$-vector subspace generated by $\Omega_{K/k}$. In other words, the composition $L \otimes_K \Omega_{K/k} \rightarrow L \otimes_{K[X]} \Omega_{K[X]/k} \rightarrow \Omega_{L/k}$ is surjective.

Now, this composition is injective, because else (here we use the exactness of the sequence) there is some $gf \in (f)/(f^2)$ which is mapped to some nonzero $\sum_i{\alpha^idb_i} + 0dX$.

But, you can check that the coefficient before $dX$ is always $g(\alpha)f’(\alpha)$: therefore $g(\alpha)=0$, hence $f|g$ and the image of $gf$ is actually zero.